# Test suite failing in Jest when using Elm

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, elm

I am building a Typescript Single Page Application. One of the endpoints returns a compiled Elm application.

When running the jest tests, I get the following error:

```
yarn run v1.7.0
$ jest
 PASS  server/tests/experience/Albums.spec.ts
 PASS  server/tests/server.spec.ts
 FAIL  client/elm-stuff/packages/elm-lang/virtual-dom/2.0.4/tests/Native/TestHelpers.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: Elm is not defined

    > 1 | Elm.Native.TestHelpers = {};
        |                            ^
      2 | Elm.Native.TestHelpers.make = function(localRuntime)
      3 | {
      4 |       localRuntime.Native = localRuntime.Native || {};

      at Object.<anonymous> (client/elm-stuff/packages/elm-lang/virtual-dom/2.0.4/tests/Native/TestHelpers.js:1:28)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 2 passed, 3 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   1 passed, 1 total
Time:        0.669s, estimated 1s
Ran all test suites.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

It looks like `Elm is not defined` in the tests.

However, I do have Elm defined in my package.json dependencies:

```
....
  "dependencies": {
    ....
    "elm": "0.18.0",
    .....
  },
 ...
```

And I can run the application without issues.

The only reference to Elm I have in the actual application is in my HTML index file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='/favicon.ico' />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css">
    <title>Print Albums</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="elm-app"></div>

    <script src="elm-compiled.js"></script>
    <script>
      const app = Elm.Main.embed(document.getElementById("elm-app"));
      app.ports.grabToken.send(window.location.search);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Do you have any idea what can go wrong? It looks like jest is going inside my Elm dependencies for some reason, instead of just my test files?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Alright, once again Stack Overflow has proven to be a great rubber duck.

What happened is :

- I develop my Elm application in the client folder.
- Some of the dependencies of the client folder have a test folder that match the jest regexp that is searching for tests.

The solution was to add `client` to the list of patterns to be ignored by jest.

```
  testPathIgnorePatterns: [
    "/node_modules/", "/client/"
  ],
```